# How to add objects programmatically in table rows FROM Right to Left

Tags: android, android-layout, android-tablelayout

I've a Table Layout and a Table Row in it. I can add buttons through code on it by the below lines:

```
for (int row = 0; row < buttonTableLayout.getChildCount(); ++row)
((TableRow) buttonTableLayout.getChildAt(row)).removeAllViews();
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

for (int row = 0; row < 3; row++) {
TableRow currentTableRow = getTableRow(row);
                for (int column = 0; column < 7; column++) {
                    Button newGuessButton = (Button)inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_button, currentTableRow, false);
                    String myName = new String(String.valueOf((row * 7) + column + 1));
                    newGuessButton.setText(myName);
                    currentTableRow.addView(newGuessButton);
                }
            }
 private TableRow getTableRow(int row) {
    return (TableRow) buttonTableLayout.getChildAt(row);
}
```

but I want to add buttons from RIGHT to LEFT. not just align from right, like:

[image]

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change your `TableRow` gravity with `currentTableRow.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT)`

Then reverse your for-loop, to keep the items order:

```
for (int column = 6; column >= 0; column--) {
     Button newGuessButton = (Button)inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_button, currentTableRow, false);
     String myName = new String(String.valueOf((row * 7) + column + 1));
     newGuessButton.setText(myName);
     currentTableRow.addView(newGuessButton);
}
```

Comment: I have to edit my picture pls take a look on it. thanks

Comment: Have you tried my answer and it didn't work ? Btw, in your new picture, the items are centered and not aligned from right to left.

Comment: Actually I've to make them centered, as I told alignment isn't my problem, add them from Right is my issue.

Comment: In this case you can just use `Gravity.CENTER` instead of `Gravity.RIGHT`, then you add your items.

Comment: My question is the ORDER of creation from Right to Left ,not just gravity or setText.

Comment: Did you look at my code or at least try it? i've already inversed the order of adding/creating the items.

Comment: Sorry , yes your code is correct. thank you so much.